# Showing that the limit of $g$ does not exist at any point $x_0$ in $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, limits

I have tried to show that the following function has no limit at any point in $\Bbb{R}$ but I haven't been able to get it to work out nicely. I would like to use an epsilon-delta argument to show this if it is possible as I feel this is the most fundamental and rigorous way of doing so. If anyone has a nice epsilon-delta argument for the following I would be very grateful:

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 ,&x \in \Bbb{Q}
\\
0 ,&x \notin \Bbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

Show that the limit of $g$ does not exist at $x_0$, $\forall$ $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$.

Thanks,

Lauren

**EDIT:** When I say the epsilon-delta argument I mean the following.
Let $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$. We say that $g$ has a limit $L$ at $x_0$ if:

$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists$ $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $0 \lt |x - x_0| \lt \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| \lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $g(x)$ has limit $l$ for $x \to x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. This means that

> $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that  $\forall x \in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ we have: $l-\epsilon < g(x)<l+\epsilon$.

Now suppose $l=0$, since in $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ there are infinitely many  rational number for which $g(x)=1$, for these numbers  the statement is not verified since $|1-0| > \epsilon$.

If $l \ne 0$ the statement is not verified because in $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ there are infinitely many non rational numbers for which $g(x)=0$, so , for these numbers, $|0-l|>\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, this is concise, simple and a very nice proof!

Answer (score 0):

By classic definition of limits in $\mathbb{R}$, you say that $f(x) \xrightarrow{x \to x_0} l$ if for all radius $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a neighbourhood $I$ of $l$ of radius less than $\varepsilon$ such that you can find a neighbourhood $J$ of $x_0$ (radius $\delta$) that makes $f(J) \subseteq I$ true.

But, as I'm sure you know, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore it is impossible for a whole neighbourhood of any point to be sent in a set different from $\{ 0, 1\}$: no matter how small the radius, between $x_0$ and $x_0 + \delta$ there are always a $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and a  $r$ $\in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$.

So choosing any $\varepsilon < 1$ proves that, no matter what $x_0$ is, $f$ cannot have a limit in that point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_{0} \in \Bbb{R}$; without loss of generality, let $0 < l := \lim _{x \to x_{0}}g(x) \leq 1.$ If $x_{0} \in \Bbb{Q}$, then there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-x_{0}| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - l|  < l/2$, implying that $g(x) > l/2$; but this is false (why?). If $x_{0} \in \Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}$, then again there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-x_{0}| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - l| < l/2$, implying that $g(x) > l/2$; but this is false for a likewise reason.

Comment: Are we presuming that the limit at $x_0$ is $g(x_0)$ here? Is this ok to do? Ie. taking $|g(x) - g(x_0)|$ rather than $|g(x) - L|$?

Comment: @LaurenHayes Yes, I mis-read your question. :)